# HDMI port and VGA port not recognized on Fedora 27

Tags: nvidia, fedora, hdmi, vga, fedora-27

My new laptop has an NVIDIA graphics card (not sure which one).  I have freshly installed Fedora 27.  However, I cannot get my HDMI or VGA port to work or even be recognized.  I've tried following the instructions at https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/ and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee (as well as a few others), but have been unsuccessful thus so far.

Here is some output from various commands for context:

```
> xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00* 

> sudo lspci -v | grep -A 15 'VGA'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07d1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel modules: i915

> sudo lspci -v | grep -A 18 '3D'
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 07d1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at ed000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel modules: nouveau
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being because I installed my OS in Basic Graphics Mode: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/46846/what-does-nomodeset-do/